# how to download Angular8 source code and make a fix for it in local

Tags: angular8

We need to fix a angular8 security bug. I need to download Angular8 source code and make a fix. Where can I get the Angular8 source code and What is the best practice for a such fix? (upgrade is not an option). We can view Angular8 source code here, https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/8.1.x/, but how to download it in local?

Comment: first run `git clone https://github.com/angular/angular.git` to get the master branch, then download `sourcetree` open this folder in sourcetree, then go to `remotes` -> choose `8.1.x` branch, same can be done with git GUI also!

Comment: Very appreciate. Also find can download a zip file from https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/8.1.x